# Mongoose Add Extra Field To Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to add new field to object.

```js
var _u = await User.findOne({_id},{_id:0, name:1, username:1, group:1}).populate({
  path: 'group',
  select: '-_id title'
})
_u.type = 'user'
console.log(_u)
```

But hasn't got `type` field. Why I can't add new field? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Mongosee hydrate it's responses, so it's not pure JavaScript object.

If you want to return pure JavaScript object, you have to add `lean()` method to the query. Also, that will improve the performance.

```
await User.findOne({ _id }, { _id:0, name:1, username:1, group:1 })
  .populate({
    path: 'group',
    select: '-_id title'
  })
  .lean()
```

You can find more info in the [official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html).